# d3 v4 getting data for bar graph tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am able to get a tooltip to work by defining the text but for the life of me I cannot get the tooltip to print text from a data file. I feel like I am messing up defining d.value even though it is being graphed just fine but I also wonder if there is something with v4 that I don't know about. I've tried moving the var statement all over the place but nothing seems to help. It usually ends up being a "Cannot read property of undefined" error. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "10")
.style("visibility", "hidden")
.text("This works just fine");
/* .text(function(d) { return d.value; }); */

d3.tsv("15.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return (d.gamedate); }))
    .paddingInner(0.1)
    .paddingOuter(0.5);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .attr("y", 15)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Game Score");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.gamedate); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
      .on("mousemove", function(d){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+400)+"px");})
      .on("mouseout", function(d){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
```

Comment: can you share the tsv so we can try out the code?

Comment: It's just two columns; gamedate which I parse into a date and value which is a number between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue is that `event` variable is not defined in the scope of the `mousemove` function. You can get the mouse values by doing the following:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    const [xMouse, yMouse] = d3.mouse(this);
    tooltip.style("top", (yMouse) + "px")
      .style("left", (xMouse) + "px")
      .text(`Gamedate ${d.gamedate} with value ${d.value}`)
})
```

I made a [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/gatuxeh/edit?js,output) in order to show how I got it to work, the data is mocked.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!